# R Chi Squared Test Prep

Tags: r, dataframe, chi-squared, hypothesis-test

Im looking to confirm that I have my Chi Square test set up correctly. I have 2 variables with 1 observation, which is the count of tweets per each. Im just trying to confirm I have it set up correctly.

Code:

```
Bridgewater_amount=328
Keenum_amount=1185

Quarterback_dataframe=data.frame(Bridgewater_amount,Keenum_amount)


chisq.test(Keenum_amount,Bridgewater_amount)
```

Comment: What hypothesis do you hope to test with just n=1?

Comment: My Hypothesis is H0: Case amount <= Bridgewater amount and H1: Case amount > Bridgewater amount

Comment: For this example, Im collecting Tweets and getting the count but a tweet could fit both of the criteria which is why I broke it out. But it looks like ill need to do it differently

Comment: The Chi square test is meant to be used on a 2x2 matrix of counts. You have a 1x2 data set, and it’s stored as a data frame.